# Check all previous elements from list in for loop Python

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, indexing

I'd like to check whether the current element in my list is larger than all the other previous elements in the list, within a for loop in Python:

```
list_height = [187, 241, 319, 213, 541, 259, 319, 381] # an example, input depends on the user
length = len(list_height)
list_floor2 = [] # empty list for storage purposes

# For loop
for i in range(length):
    floor1 = list_height[i]
    if i == 0:
        list_floor2.append(floor2)
    elif list_height[i] > list_height[0] and list_height[i] > list_height[i - 1]:
        floor1 = list_hoogte[i - 1]
        list_floor2.append(floor2)
```

Instead of `list_height[i] > list_height[i - 1]` in the elif statement I'd like to not only check whether the current index `(i) >`  the previous element in list_height (so not only index `i - 1`), BUT whether current index `(i) >` **all** previous elements in list_height.

How can I select all previous elements in the list? I've tried `all()` and `list_height[:i]` but I always get the same error:

`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'`

Comment: Your code doesn't run (`NameError: name 'floor2' is not defined. Did you mean: 'floor1'?`)! Also, can you provide your _expected_ output, so people can ensure their code works to your expectations, please?

Comment: think of it this way - assume you've reached the i-th element somehow and you know for sure that `a[i]` is larger than `a[i-1], a[i-2]` etc. Now, when you check `a[i+1]`, do you really need to check _all_ of the previous elements `a[i], a[i-1], a[i-2]`? Or just one of them? If yes, which one?

Comment: @gog - that only works if comparison between the list elements is always transitive... which is fine for integers, but may not be true in the general case; consider rock-paper-scissors...

Comment: what if two consecutive elements are equal ? Show the expected output as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `enumerate` and `max`,

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(list_height) if v >= max(list_height[:i+1])]

# Output
[187, 241, 319, 541]
```

Comment: I like list comprehensions. Very tidy answer.

Comment: This combines the limitations of both of the other answers; it's O(n²) and it depends on transitive comparison

Answer (score 2):

As already in the comments mentioned, you don't actually need to check every single element till the current index. Check in each iteration for the maximum value, if the current number is bigger, you have a current maximum `currrent_max`, else you continue. If there is a new maximum (which automatically is also bigger than every number before), you assign that number as `current_max` and append the current value in the second list.

```
list_height = [187, 241, 319, 213, 541, 259, 319, 381]
list_floor2 = []

for i, num in enumerate(list_height):
    if i==0:
        list_floor2.append(num)
        current_max = num
    else:
        if num >= current_max:
            current_max = num
            list_floor2.append(num)

print(list_floor2)
```

```
[187, 241, 319, 541]
```

Comment: This only works if the list contains numbers or other items that have a transitive `>=`; it won't work if the items are [dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_dice) or [election candidates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox) or [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitivity)

Comment: yes, but that is what the OP provided as example and therefore it works.

Comment: It's commented as "input depends on user", so it's reasonable to point out limitations?

Comment: ok, yes, that's true. Considered that it is a valid point, but I more understood it that the input list (of numbers) is given by a User Input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

The for-loop will iterate through the `list_height` list. And using the `all` function, will check to see if the current value (`value[1]`) is greater than any previous number in the list. If True, it will print the line with a `True` value at the end, otherwise it will print a `False` value at the end.

```py
list_height = [187, 241, 319, 213, 541, 259, 319, 381]

for value in enumerate(list_height):
    if all(x < value[1] for x in list_height[0:value[0]]):
        print(f"{value[0]}-{value[1]} : True")
    else:
        print(f"{value[0]}-{value[1]} : False")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0-187 : True
1-241 : True
2-319 : True
3-213 : False
4-541 : True
5-259 : False
6-319 : False
7-381 : False
```

Or if you want more succinct code:

```py
list_height = [187, 241, 319, 213, 541, 259, 319, 381]

for i,num in enumerate(list_height):
    val = all(x < num for x in list_height[0:i])
    print(f"{i}-{num} : {val}")
```

This provides the same output.

Comment: In worst case, `all` will take O(n) so overall, this will take 0(n^2) ?

Comment: Yeah, this is O(n²); if the list items are guaranteed to have transitive comparison, it'll be more efficient to use [Rabinzel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74012502/683329)

Answer (score 0):

```
length = len(list_height)
list_floor2 = [] # empty list for storage purposes

# check whether the current element in my list is larger than all the other previous elements in the list
def Check(i):
    is_larger=True
    for j in range(i):
        if(list_height[j] > list_height[i]):
            is_larger=False
            break
    return is_larger 
# For loop
for i in range(length):
    floor1 = list_height[i]
    if Check(i):
        list_floor2.append(floor1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from code-only answers. Explain what your code does and how it solves the OP's problem. Thanks!